# Preventing user from entering alphabet & push the model into array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular & trying to prevent the user from entering alphabet into text field and at the same item push the model onto array. But the logic doesn't seem to work perfectly and sometimes allows alphabets. How can I prevent special characters like $,% from being entered ?

HTML

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in arr track by $index">
        <input type="text" number ng-change="itemChange()"  ng-model="item"  />
        <button ng-click="add()">Add Item</button>
      </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
app.directive('number', function(){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl){
                elem.bind('keyup', function(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    var text = this.value;
                    this.value = text.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,'');

                }); 
            }
        };
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.arr = [];

  //Initialize with one element
  $scope.arr[0] = '';

  //Push when there is a change in the input
  $scope.itemChange = function() {
    $scope.arr[this.$index] = this.item;
  }

  //Add an empty item at the end
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.arr[$scope.arr.length] = '';
  }
});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/t8OE5uJ578zgkiUTjHgt?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.directive('alphabetonly', function(){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl){
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi,'');   
                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                     ctrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                     ctrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

See [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JecklBW9YcWBi97VuNX4?p=info).

Comment: Regarding alphabets and special characters, i was confused by the question as to whether we want to disallow alphabets or special characters, the regex here removes special characters, but it can be customized with any regex we wish.

Comment: thank you for the plnk it prevents special characters from being added and works beautifully how can I customize regex to prevent alphabets ?

Comment: I'm not terribly good at regexes, but there are thousands online, but for example this: `/[^0-9]/g` only allows numbers.